# Are temporary (one month) links to my site from a powerful source good for SEO?

Tags: google, links

If a powerful site links to my site, but removes it after a month,is useful or harmful for my Google rankings?

Comment: *Are temporary (one month) links to my site from a powerful source good for SEO?* Short answer? No. But it does no harm either. If you are thinking there is a lingering effect, well yes that would be reasonable only as long as the removal of the link is not discovered. Once it is discovered, any effect disappears. Cheers!!